# What is the focus of $f(x)=\exp(\frac{1}{\log(x)})?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections

Trying hard to find the focus of $f(x)$ but it doesn't fit in great with the standard equation for conics. I tried to algebraically manipulate $f(x)$ but couldn't proceed after getting logarithms in the standard equation. What am I missing? I've been taught to use a rotation matrix to transform the hyperbola to the orientable form, compute the solution and then transform back. I could have made errors in the process, so thanks for the help.

Comment: Is this really a conic?

Comment: I don't think this is a hyperbola. Look at https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ln+x+ln+y%3D1 , especially in the corner https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+e%5E%281%2Fln+x%29%2C+0%3Cx%3C1

Comment: It's an involution, and I've been able to show that it is a hyperbola, and so I thought that it should have a focus

Comment: @ultradark your function is indeed an involution, but is not a hyperbola (it doesn't decay at $\infty$ like a parabola; you can get a good approximation using Pade Approximants for the exponential though)

Comment: Oh I thought it was, what is it then? So you're saying for $x,y>1$ it's not a hyperbola?

Comment: I'm confused, why would it decaying at infinity like a parabola have something to do with it being a hyperbola

Comment: Take care that the function is discontinuous at $x=1$ and you have two branches, one for $0<x<1$ and another for $x>1$ which "looks" more or less like an hyperbola but which is not.

Comment: Use [GeoGebra to plot your function](https://www.geogebra.org/graphing/uq4fr6ks) and the hyperbola $y=e^2/x$, then watch the differences.

Comment: oh I think I see now that $f(x)$ decays slower as $x \to \infty$

Comment: I think I got confused because wikipedia says it is a "hyperbolic involution"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)=e^{\frac{1}{\log(x)}}$ can be rewritten as $\ln(x)\ln(y)=1$ which is a rectangular hyperbola in log-log space. $f(x)$ is then the image of the hyperbola $xy=1.$ The foci of $xy=1$ are $(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$ and $(-\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2}).$ Transforming the foci of $xy=1$ accordingly, the foci for $\ln(x)\ln(y)=1$ become $(e^{\sqrt{2}},e^\sqrt{2})$ and $(e^{-\sqrt{2}},e^{-\sqrt{2}}).$